# add variable value to github action name

Tags: github, github-actions

How do I create a github workflow step name with a variable value.

I tried this but it does not work.

```
name: Publish
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io

jobs:
  Publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Log into Container registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
```

Comment: You might want to wait until the job reaches the step. At first it's visible as ${{ env.NAME }} but when it gets there it gets replaced by the proper value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you tried it, but reproducing the workflow [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester67.yml) with your implementation (as below) actually worked for me.

```
name: Publish

on:
  push:

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io

jobs:
  Publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Log into Container registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        run: echo "Ok"
```

The job **step name** was generated dynamically according to the workflow `env variable` set.

[Here is the workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3320382662/jobs/5486697734)

[image: evidence]

Comment: Weird at first it was not working for me and now it just started working. Thanks for going to the trouble of testing this.

Comment: I see why mine was not working. I was going back and forth with a if statement and if you set the if statement to not run after the name it doesn';t add the variable. Example:  - name: Log into Container registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: ${{ !contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '!RELEASE') }}

Comment: Good to know the order may matter in how you configure your steps with env variables! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Since this does not seem supported, it is better to add an echo which prints the variable, before one processing it:

```yaml
name: Publish
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io

jobs:
  Publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Log into Container registry 
        run: echo "registry is '$REGISTRY'"
```

After that, for [runtime variables](https://microsoft.github.io/code-with-engineering-playbook/continuous-delivery/devops-provider-recipes/github-actions/runtime-variables/runtime-variables/), you can add conditions:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - actions-test-branch

jobs:
  Echo-On-Commit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout Repository"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: "Set flag from Commit"
        env:
          COMMIT_VAR: ${{ contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[commit var]') }}
        run: |
          if ${COMMIT_VAR} == true; then
            echo "flag=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            echo "flag set to true"
          else
            echo "flag=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            echo "flag set to false"
          fi

      - name: "Use flag if true"
        if: env.flag
        run: echo "Flag is available and true"
```

Comment: Thanks what does echo "flag=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV do. I thought echo was just to log in console not to set variables ?

Comment: @me-me It is to [set the environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable): "You can make an environment variable available to any subsequent steps in a workflow job by defining or updating the environment variable and writing this to the `GITHUB_ENV` environment file."